# Matching columns from one data frame to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes (T and S). They both share a column name called ID but S has a latitude and longitude column. I would like to go through both data frames and match each lat and long to their appropriate IDs (station IDs in each DF is not in the same order) in dataframe T. These DFs are not the same size but they are both very large with some duplicates.

Comment: Elaborate on your last 3 words.

Comment: Perhaps start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right).

Answer (score 0):

```
print pd.merge(T, S, on='long' 'lat', how='inner')
```